# Removing list item with specific character

Tags: python, list

My question is:

Suppose I have a list:

```
l=['asd1', 'jkl1', 'mno1', 'pqr2', 'stu2']
```

How can I delete all the items from the list that contains '2' character without iterating through the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "without iterating through the list"... ?

Comment: What do you mean by **without iterating through the list**?

Comment: @greole wow... that's err, slightly freaky :)

Comment: without visiting the items list you can only guess what's in them

Comment: You can use builtin functions, but they will still internally iterate over the list. Do you mean *without explicitly iterating* ?

Comment: Yes, without explicit iteration. BTW, I got it. Thanks for your inputs! :D

Comment: @JonClements: Hahaha just realised it now! That was a matter of seconds

Answer (score 2):

Without iterating through the list? You simply can't; you can't do any better than `O(n)` here, you need to work through the list at least once to find out which items to keep and which to remove. A list comprehension would be relatively efficient:

```
l = [i for i in l if '2' not in i]
```

The only exception is if you have more information; if you knew `'2'` would *only appear once* (or `x` times), for example, you could stop when you find the first and only appearance (although this wouldn't help in your example, as the `'2'`s are in the last items).

Answer (score 1):

You can filter items from a list by using `filter`.

```
l=['asd1', 'jkl1', 'mno1', 'pqr2', 'stu2']
l = filter(lambda item: "2" not in item, l)
print l
```

Result:

```
['asd1', 'jkl1', 'mno1']
```

The implementation of `filter` almost certainly involves iteration, but this is invisible to the end-user, so it may be satisfactory to you.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've been wanting. :))

Comment: @SunnyNanda He probably didnt want to code the iteration and wanted an already existing function.

Comment: I think this is how I define "without iteration" for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions for that, but at the end not matter what you'll have to iterate through the list

```
l=['asd1', 'jkl1', 'mno1', 'pqr2', 'stu2']
filt_char = '2'
new_list = [ x for x in l if filt_char not in x]
```